# Find $\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(x+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

As stated in the title.

My attempt. Dividing through $(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}$.
$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(x+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{(\frac{x+1}{x-2})^{\frac{2}{3}}-(\frac{x-1}{x-2})^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(\frac{x+2}{x-2})^{\frac{2}{3}}-1}$$
L'Hopital
$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\frac{2}{3}(\frac{x+1}{x_2})^{-\frac{1}{3}}(\frac{x-2-(x+1)}{(x-2)^2})-\frac{2}{3}(\frac{x-1}{x-2})^{-\frac{1}{3}}(\frac{x-2-(x-1)}{(x-2)^2})}{\frac{2}{3}(\frac{x+2}{x-2})^{-\frac{1}{3}}(\frac{x-2-(x+2)}{(x-2)^2})}=\lim_{x\ \to \infty}{\frac{3(x+1)^{-\frac{1}{3}}-(-1)(x-1)^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{(x+2)^{-\frac{1}{3}}(-4)}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{3(1+\frac{1}{x})^{-\frac{1}{3}}-(1-\frac{1}{x})^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{4(1+\frac{2}{x})^{-\frac{1}{3}}}}=\frac{3-1}{(4)(1)}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Is this correct and is there a more elegant way of doing it?

EDIT: strictly speaking L'Hopital is not applicable with $x \to \infty$ so just got lucky here...

Comment: Use the difference of squares, then the difference of cubes, formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way to do it. Dividing by $x^{2/3}$ yields $$ \frac{(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(x+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}} =  \frac{(1+\frac 1x)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(1-\frac 1x)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(1+\frac 2 x)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(1-\frac 2x)^{\frac{2}{3}}} 
$$

Substitute $t = 1/x$. Then $$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(x+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}} = \lim_{t \to 0+}\frac{(1+ t)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(1-t)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(1+ 2t)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(1- 2t)^{\frac{2}{3}}}  $$

Putting $f(t) = (1+t)^{2/3}$ yields \begin{align} \lim_{t \to 0+}\frac{(1+ t)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(1-t)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(1+ 2t)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(1- 2t)^{\frac{2}{3}}} &= \lim_{t \to 0
+} \frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{f(2t)-f(-2t)} \\ &= \frac 12 \cdot\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{t} \cdot \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{2t}{f(2t)-f(-2t)}\end{align}

Note that $$ \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{t}= \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{f(t)-f(0)}{t} + \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{f(-t)-f(0)}{-t} = 2f'(0)=\frac 23$$

Thus $$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(x+2)^{\frac{2}{3}}-(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}} = \frac 12 \cdot\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{f(t)-f(-t)}{t} \cdot \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{2t}{f(2t)-f(-2t)} = \frac 12 \cdot \frac 23 \cdot \frac 32 = \frac 12$$

Comment: You use many limit operations (*lim of prod is prod of lims* and/or *lim of sum is sum of lims*) without justification that they actually exist.

Comment: @VIVID $\lim_{x \to a}\frac{()}{indeterminate \neq 0, \infty}=\frac{\lim_{x \to a}()}{\lim_{x \to a}indeterminate \neq 0, \infty}$ right?

Answer (score 3):

From the binomial theorem, we know $(1+y)^n\approx1+ny$ for $y\approx0$. Divide both numerator and denominator by $x^{2/3}$. The limit is$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\frac{\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{\left(1+\frac2x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\left(1-\frac2x\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1+\frac{2/3}x-1+\frac{2/3}x}{1+\frac{4/3}x-1+\frac{4/3}x}=1/2.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it without using L'hopital, or series expansion :

Using the identity $ a^{3}-b^{3}=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{2}+ab+b^{2}\right) $, we have : $$ \left(x+1\right)^{2}-\left(x-1\right)^{2}=\left(\left(x+1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\left(\left(x+1\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}+\left(x^{2}-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right) $$

And : $$ \left(x+2\right)^{2}-\left(x-2\right)^{2}=\left(\left(x+2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\left(x-2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\left(\left(x+2\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}+\left(x^{2}-4\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(x-2\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right) $$

Thus : \begin{aligned}\lim_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{\left(x+2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}-\left(x-2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}}}&=\lim_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{\left(\left(x+1\right)^{2}-\left(x-1\right)^{2}\right)\left(\left(x+2\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}+\left(x^{2}-4\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(x-2\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)}{\left(\left(x+2\right)^{2}-\left(x-2\right)^{2}\right)\left(\left(x+1\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}+\left(x^{2}-1\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(x-1\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)}}\\ &=\lim_{x\to +\infty}{\frac{\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}+\left(1-\frac{4}{x^{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(1-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}}{2\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}+\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}+\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)}}\\ &=\frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

With difference of squares and difference of cubes, you get that the limit simplifies to

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{(x+1)-(x-1)}{(x+2)-(x-2)}\cdot \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

because $f$ and $g$ both grow at the rate $\sim 6 x$ for large $x$.

Comment: How do I go from $()^\frac{1}{3}-()^{\frac{1}{3}}$ to the $()^3-()^3$ formula?

Comment: @ChernSimons you don't. You use $a^3-b^3 = \cdots$ with $a^3 =x+1$, etc

Comment: It would help if you told us what $f$ and $g$ are.

Comment: @Tonyk I didn't mention this in the post, but part of the point of presenting it this way is to show OP the benefits of looking for patterns. It really doesn't matter what $f$ and $g$ are. Because of the similarity between the numerator and denominator, and how difference of squares and cubes will always add on the other side, both functions will grow at the same rate with the same coefficient. Intuitively this is because for large $x$ the $+1$ etc don't matter when nothing is being subtracted.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(x+1)^{2/3}-(x-1)^{2/3}}{(x+2)^{2/3}-(x-2)^{2/3}}=\dfrac12\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\dfrac{(1+t)^{2/3}-(1-t)^{2/3}}t}{\dfrac{(1+2t)^{2/3}-(1-2t)^{2/3}}{2t}}=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{\lim_{t\to0}f(t)}{\lim_{t\to0}f(2t)}$$

Now for $\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{(1+t)^{2/3}-(1-t)^{2/3}}t,$  set $(1+t)^{1/3}=p,(1-t)^{1/3}=q$

$\implies p^3-q^3=2t$ and $\implies p\to q, q\to1$

$$\lim_{t\to0}f(t)=\lim_{p\to q, q\to1}\dfrac{2(p-q)}{p^3-q^3}=\lim_{q\to1}\dfrac2{3q^2}=?$$